# Power Automate - Microsoft Forms to Excel with branching

Tags: excel, forms, power-automate

I am using Microsoft Forms with Power Automate to update an Excel spread sheet in teams.

The form is complex and has branching. For example when I click through the form I can select items that belong to me, however the next person has their own items (hmmm that's not very clear).

Using branching I have over 50 sections called Equipment. Each of those equipment sections has items relevant to a user.

When the user submits the form, Power Automate updates the excel spreadsheet with Equipment, Equipment2, Equipment3, equipment4... etc.
[image]

How can I have it so all the data is pushed into one Excel Column, Equipment and not spread through 50 Equipment# columns?

[image]

Regards,

Michael